# Hosted CMS + MSSQL DB = best solution for sports website?

Tags: sql-server, content-management-system

**Goal:** I want to create a website for my High School's Soccer team to show game info, player info, and historical stats/records for as little $ as possible.

I originally planned on writing an ASP.NET site, so I spent some time setting up and loading all the data into MS SQL.  However, I've realized I'd rather find a simpler solution than me trying to come up with everything that goes with creating/maintaining the site.

The biggest factor here is tying the database to the site.  I want to continue to update the data going forward without messing with the front end too much. I've developed in ASP.NET/C#/VB.NET and am comfortable with CSS/web dev/blogging, so I'm able to do a little dirty work if need be.

**Question:** Is there a good CMS option for my situation?  Also, where to host it on the cheap?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a CMS developer for 5 years.  Having been through all that, I wouldn't write my own for a single, relatively simple site.

There's SO many options out there.  Obviously, the standard Joomla/Wordpress/Drupal solutions are there and are SO cost effective to build.  Free software + $5 a month hosting (my personal fav is HostGator) and you've got yourself a very good site.  Joomla offers some plugins such as calendars, groups and authorization, etc that makes it ideal for a club or sports team setting.  Joomla even has [free plugins that are specifically made for tracking sports stats and results.](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/sports-a-games/sports)  I did sports stats on websites professionally for the US Swimming and Cycling teams as well as two NCAA conferences.....and they aren't fun to deal with at all!

That being said, none of those are .net based!

DotNetNuke is where everyone on the .net side seems to turn.  This is my personal feeling, but DotNetNuke and Wordpress both fail in that they are somewhat strict with layouts unless you really know what you're doing.  For example, look at a bunch of sites and chances are you'll be able to tell which ones are Wordpress based.  That was always my top measure of flexibility.

I'm intrigued right now by [Concrete5](http://www.concrete5.org/) because of its ability to content manage any layout with minimal modification.  Again, it's PHP based.  My personal feeling is that you'd actually come out ahead "switching sides" because of the considerable amount of work product and community that the big free CMS packages offer.  Setup is a breeze, so knowledge is less of an issue.  But ultimately your comfort zone is what matters.

Comment: +1 for switching sides. I'm a .NET developer, but when it comes to low cost CMS solutions, I don't think there's anything out there in the .NET world, and so many options when you look at PHP. You also don't have to worry about Microsoft licenses, anymore...

Comment: Funny you mention that.  I worked on two sites for Olympic sports teams.  One was written in .Net at a cost of over $1 million in consultants, servers, staff, and licenses.  I did the majority of the other in-house with one other coworker on PHP/MySQL for the cost of our salaries plus the cost of 3 cheap servers.  The more expensive solution was published as a Case Study (success) by Microsoft.  Both do essentially the same thing and serve a similar audience.  I think it's a good example that you have to really scrutinize the tools you choose to use for the job at hand.